# WCF - communication object cannot be used for communication

Tags: wcf

I am new to this WCF stuff and I need to get the project involving WCF at work. So, I am testing the water by creating a very simple wcf using NetTcpBinding hardcoding the ip address to simplify the configuration but I was not able to get it to work. Please take a look and see if there is something that jumps at you, I would appreciate it if you could point me to something I have done incorrectly. 
I have a WCFLib, WCFHost and WCFClient. If everything is on the same machine, it is fine and dandy and the client and host worked perfect and the result was correct. However, If the host is on one machine and the client on a different one in the same subnet no firewall (the client could ping the host successfully) and I tried to run the client then click the "=" button in the application, I got this error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WCFLib.ICalculator.Add(Int32 arg1, Int32 arg2)
   at WCFClient.CalculatorClient.bResult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Frank\Testing\WCFClient\CalculatorClient.cs:line 37
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WCFClient
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/xxx/WCFClient/bin/Debug/WCFClient.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18037 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
```

This following are my WCFClient, WCFHost and WCFLib codes: The codes compiled and run successfully when the host and the client were on the same machine. Error occurred only when they were on separate machine on the same subnet where one machine could ping the other.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WCFLib;

namespace WCFHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000");
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFLib
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/WCFLib")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract(Name="AddInt")]
        int Add(int arg1, int arg2);
        [OperationContract(Name = "AddDouble")]
        Double Add(Double arg1, Double arg2);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    // You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "WCFLib.ContractType".
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFLib
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Calculator : ICalculator
    {
        public int Add(int arg1, int arg2)
        {
            return arg1+arg2;
        }
        public Double Add(Double arg1, Double arg2)
        {
            return arg1 + arg2;
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WCFLib;

namespace WCFClient
{

    public partial class CalculatorClient : Form
    {
        public ICalculator proxy;
         public CalculatorClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChannelFactory<ICalculator> ch;
            ch = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000");
            proxy = ch.CreateChannel();

        }

         private void bAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         private void bResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             tboxResult.Text=proxy.Add(12, 45).ToString();
         }


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a path to your URL when hosting and connecting:

e.g.: "net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/CalcService"